# SonarQube Jacoco Coverage Reports (.ec & xml) reports not displayed together

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

Our SonarQube Server Environment details as follows:

```
SonarQube Version – 6.7.7(LTS).
sonar-java-plugin-5.12.1.17771.jar
sonar-jacoco-plugin-1.0.1.143.jar
```

I have two jacoco code-coverage reports (coverage.ec & jacoco.xml), the below are the project property values defined.

```
sonar.jacoco.reportPaths= code-coverage/connected/coverage.ec
sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=jacocoTestReport/jacoco.xml
```

Together it is not getting displayed in SonarQube Dashboard. Whereas individually it displays.It is not possible to display both?

Comment: sonar.jacoco.reportPaths is deprecated see:[here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Unit+Tests+and+Coverage+Results+Import)

Comment: Actually this property works to import (coverage.ec)  report individually.

Comment: Actually as correctly pointed by @jeroen-heier property `sonar.jacoco.reportPaths` was deprecated in favor of only `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths`. Attempt to set both leads to the following message in log `Both 'sonar.jacoco.reportPaths' and 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' were set. 'sonar.jacoco.reportPaths' is deprecated therefore, only 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' will be taken into account.`, which IMO perfectly explains your difficulty. So pass two XML reports using `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths` after generation of XML report from your `coverage.ec`.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will convert my coverage.ec report into xml and then I will import both the reports using sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths= property.

Comment: I have aggregated (merged) xml for multiple modules and I have set file location against sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths property. I am still not able to see code coverage in sonarQube(6.7.4) dashboard. It is showing 0.0% coverage however when I run maven verify locally it is showing 90%+ coverage in (index.html). Is there any changes I need to do in SonarQube dashboard to pick-up xml file.

Comment: Did you add sonar.java.binaries and 
sonar.java.test.binaries in your sonar-project.properties  file?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @Kishore

Comment: @Anoneironaut, As per sonarqube desgin .ec and .XML can't be integrated to dashboard. At a time any one format only possible.

Comment: I'm also having a lot of trouble with this, I can't figure out how to get it to show the coverage in sonar but when running verify the HTML reports show it correctly